# nodejs python or twisted

Tags: python, node.js, web, twisted

I'm new to web development and going to make a website which responses with data received from request to web-service(facebook for e.g.) and how to choose what is more useful here:

- nodejs has an callback model which allows not to wait while gathering data for user from other services (but i've broken my fingers and my brain after trying to make a kind of class in javascript with inheritance and the whole server drops after unhandled error in script)

  python is very convinient in working with diff. kinds of data, it's more convinient for me, former C++ developer

  yesterday i've read about twisted python that also uses callbacks

Help me please to choose what to use, better - performance, simple code

Comment: If you want an asynchronous server, you either need callbacks (with or without promises/futures), threads, coroutines, green threads, or explicit async scheduling. You don't want the last one, but other than that, it's up to you to read up on the other options and decide which one makes sense to you, then you find a framework that works that way. Just asking "which one is simpler code" is meaningless, because it's different for every programmer.

Comment: Also, performance is obviously a completely separate question to simplest to code in—and often they're at cross-purposes. So, do you want the simplest thing that's fast enough, or the fastest thing that's simple enough, or something different? And, if one of those, what's the cutoff for "enough"? Without knowing that, nobody can answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback model might make your code more verbose but WAIT! there is a solution! Check out
[waitfor](https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor).
Anyway, if it's a personal project then no one is forcing you to use node.js for webapp development.You should go with what makes you more comfortable. If you like developing in python then go for it! :)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/); it uses python (which you said is more convenient) and is also very commonly used for web development.

Comment: excuse me, but now it doesn't matter for me what WF to use, the question is language. django is good i've heard but it's not time for it)